# How do I make a scatterplot of two columns in R when

Tags: r, plot, scatter-plot

I am trying to make a scatterplot of two columns (V13 and V21). I want the row number on the x axis and each column on the y axis - on the same figure. So each column has its own set of y values. I want the row number to be on the x axis . When I go to plot this, however, I get this:

> Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) :    'x' and 'y'
> lengths differ

The dataframe I'm working with is called "Vs.highvar". The data has 1000 obs of 2 variables, and I want the x axis to be the number of rows (1000), so I guess that's the problem. How do I do this? Do I have to split the data into two separate columns/two separate dataframes? I'm very new to R. I've tried `split()`, `separate()`, `plot()`, `ggplot2.scatterplot()`, `scatterplot()`.

Code so far:

```
Vs <- read.csv(file="x.csv", 
               header=TRUE,
               fill=TRUE)

#find variables with largest variance 
head(Vs)
variances <- apply(X=Vs, MARGIN=2, FUN=var)
sortedvars <- sort(variances, 
                   decreasing=TRUE, 
                   index.return=TRUE)$ix[1:2]

Vs.highvar <- Vs[, sortedvars]
Vs.highvar #returns variables V13 and V21

#create scatterplot
plot(nrow(Vs.highvar), Vs.highvar$V13, 
     main="Variances")
```

Comment: I think the issue is that your "nrow(Vs.highvar)" produces a single number, whereas "Vs.highvar$V13" will produce 1000 different numbers. Here is an example that might be what you want: ```df1<-data.frame(y = rnorm(1000))      plot(x = 1:length(df1$y),df1$y)```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you want the plot to look like. Nevertheless, you always need a similar number of x and y values. `nrow(Vs.highvar)` is a single number.

If the x-axis should be a running number (a counter) then you need a sequence which you can get with `1:nrow(Vs.highvar)`: try `plot(1:nrow(Vs.highvar), Vs.highvar$V13, main="Variances")`.

(Otherwise, if you want to use the same value for multiple y values you would need to replicate the total number of rows ( nrow(Vs.highvar) ). You can do this with the `rep()` function.
Try: `plot(rep(nrow(Vs.highvar), nrow(Vs.highvar)), Vs.highvar$V13, main="Variances")`.

Also, there is the `points()` function with an argument `add`. When set to TRUE you can add the second data series (=column of the table) to an existing plot.

```
plot(1:nrow(Vs.highvar), Vs.highvar$V13, main="Variances")
points(1:nrow(Vs.highvar), Vs.highvar$V21, add=T)
```

Edit: I restructured the text above.

Comment: This helped me create the plot itself, although I can't make sense of it. I used Basically I want

Comment: Sorry, I messed up the highlighting and went a bit to fast with my thoughts. I try to keep it in mind next time.